# React 16 Fragments Misuse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fragment

In `React` version 16, `Fragments` were implemented. I love using them!

My question is, what if I use `Fragments` unnecessarily. Does it matter? Can I stick them in as boilerplate for my code in-case I want to add adjacent elements later or is that bad practice.

And if it is bad practice. Why? Since they don't get rendered in the `DOM` anyway. Does it matter if I add it or not?

It just feels wrong and I want some clarity there.

Comment: I doesn't really matter, but why would you want to do that? You end up with more code unnecessarily and should you add more adjacent code in the future it only takes 2 seconds to add a fragment...

Comment: Well I have a colleague that keeps telling me it doesn't matter so he keeps adding the stupid boilerplate code. I want to remove them but then he complains that he might (like 0.05% change of that happening) use it later...

Comment: I personally don't like that practice either, but it isn't dangerous or "wrong". It's almost equivalent to having every component render start with a wrapping `div` but with the difference that it doesn't render to DOM. However, depending on your app size and how many components you have, you are increasing your bundle size slightly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The use of the `Fragment` tag will only affect the bundle size of the project in a very minor way.

Best practice would be to only use a `Fragment` when it is necessary.